# Dynamic values using SimpleSchema / Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I was just wondering if anyone knows if its possible to have 'dynamic values' when using 'simple schema' & mongodb? It is for a meteor project.

Here's more information on [simpleschema](https://github.com/mercmobily/SimpleSchema).

We have a form that has 'attributes' that are user defined in the front end and need to add these to the simple schema / mongodb, rather than have a 'set in stone' data model that is then checked against.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. A SimpleSchema object is, as the name stands, just an object. You can build as many as you want, especially on the front-end. If the user defines attributes, why not use these attributes to create a new schema for example? Please post some more explanations/code to show what you try to achieve, and where you are stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

In your schema use:

```
attributes: {
  type: Object,
  blackbox: true
}
```

Comment: thanks michel, i'll give the blackbox approach a try and let you know how i get on! x

Comment: Hy michel.. Ended up grabbing a book on mongo db design patterns.. Its helping! Thanks again!